# Strange delay on Win UDP socket during GC

Tags: python, performance, sockets, garbage-collection, delay

When closing a UDP socket which previously sent to a host known by my router, it takes forever to close. What is going on, and how can I circumvent?

```
$ python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket,time
>>> def strange_delay(host):
...     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
...     s.sendto(b'whatever', (host,80))
...     t = time.perf_counter()
...     s = None        # This will take a huge amount of time. GC@work?
...     print('Strange delay is', time.perf_counter()-t)
...
>>> strange_delay('google.com')
Strange delay is 0.0003058695615487909
>>> strange_delay('hostname-known-to-my-router-but-currently-offline')
Strange delay is 2.5981389268589035
```

I'm seeing the exact same thing on Python 2. It always happens on Windows, it never happens on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Windows-ism. I found the same problem with Python 2.7 using IP addresses that were not on the network. I can also replicate the problem using Java. This article seems to give a good description of the problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2013/10/09/udp-closesocket-takes-upto-5-seconds-to-return-in-disconnect-remote-host-down-scenario-due-to-pending-data-to-send.aspx